# Flink-Kafka in Python: Deserialization Error

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink, pyflink

I'm trying to build a custom tumbling window with PyFlink by reading data from Kafka source. I have a Kafka input topic made by 7 partitions. My KafkaProducer sends a message every 15 secs. This is an example: [Producer messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4ohc.png).
Each message is sent to a specific partition based on the key (id_channel). Both message and key are serialized as JSON:

```
class Producer:
def __init__(self, topic):
    self.producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'], value_serializer=self.json_serializer, key_serializer=self.json_serializer)
    self.topic = topic

def create_message(self):
    channel, id_channel = self.get_channel()
    id_client = str(uuid.uuid1())
    os.environ['TZ'] = 'Europe\Rome'
    current_millis = round(datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000)
    return {
        "tms": current_millis,
        "id_client": id_client,
        "channel": channel,
        "id_channel": id_channel
    }

def send(self, msg, key=None):
    self.producer.send(topic=self.topic, value=msg, key=key) \
        .add_callback(self.on_send_success) \
        .add_errback(self.on_send_error)

@staticmethod
def json_serializer(msg):
    return json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8')
```

Messages are correctly sent in the "audienceInput" topic. Now, I want to read messages in Streaming mode by using the *StreamTableEnvironment*; apply a group by on id_channel and count how many users are logged to each channel, using tumbling windows of 60secs. I set up the environment and created Kafka Source/Sink Table with DDL:

```
# 1. Create streaming environment
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()

settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance() \
    .in_streaming_mode() \
    .use_blink_planner() \
    .build()

# 2. Create table environment
tbl_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(stream_execution_environment=env,
                                        environment_settings=settings)
tbl_conf = tbl_env.get_config().get_configuration()

# 3. Add Kafka connector dependency
kafka_jar = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/jars/"),
                         'flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.14.2.jar')

tbl_conf.set_string("pipeline.jars", "file://{}".format(kafka_jar))
src_ddl = """
    CREATE TABLE audienceInput (
        tms BIGINT,
        id_client STRING,
        channel STRING,
        id_channel STRING,
        proctime AS PROCTIME()
    ) WITH (
        'connector' = 'kafka',
        'topic' = 'audienceInput',
        'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
        'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
        'value.format' = 'json',
        'key.format' = 'json',
        'key.fields' = 'id_channel'
    )
    """

snk_ddl = """
    CREATE TABLE audienceOutput (
        id_channel STRING,
        window_start TIMESTAMP(3),
        window_end TIMESTAMP(3),
        num_users INT
    ) WITH (
        'connector' = 'kafka',
        'topic' = 'audienceOutput',
        'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
        'format' = 'json',
        'json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true'
    )
"""
tbl_env.execute_sql(source)
tbl_env.execute_sql(sink)

# Create and initiate loading of source Table
tbl = tbl_env.from_path('audienceInput')

# Aggregate
audience_measurement = tbl.window(Tumble.over(lit(60).seconds).on(tbl.proctime).alias('w')) \
    .group_by(col('w'), tbl.id_channel) \
    .select(tbl.id_channel,
            col('w').start.alias('window_start'),
            col('w').end.alias('window_end'),
            tbl.id_client.count.alias("num_users")
            )

audience_measurement.execute_insert('audienceOutput').wait()
table_env.execute_sql("SELECT * FROM audienceInput").print()
```

However, when I execute the program the following error is raised: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZH11.png).
I think the problem is on the source: errors raised when parsing incoming data.

As suggested I've added the kafka-clients dependency. Now a new error is raised:[Failed to execute sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxnnc.png).

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing any dependencies?

Thanks.

Comment: That class comes from kafka-clients JAR, which seems to be missing from your classpath, yes. The error is when producing, not parsing

Comment: @OneCricketeer you're right, it's true. I've added this dependency but still not working. The error is raised on audience_measurement.execute_insert('audienceOutput').wait():
pyflink.util.exceptions.TableException: Failed to execute sql
  at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:775)
  at ...

Comment: Can you update the post with the full new exception?

Comment: It's updated: there's a png with the output error

Comment: I'm not familiar with `execute_insert` method. Have you tried just a regular [`INSERT INTO`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/sql/insert/)? Or even using the regular Kafka producer without flink-sql?

Comment: @OneCricketeer `insert_into` is deprecated in version 1.11. It's suggested to use `execute_insert`. I'm new to PyFlink, so I'm not skilled yet and I cannot solve this problem

Comment: The latest nightly documentation still shows insert into raw query, however https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/table/upsert-kafka/